# How do you start a markdown list at 10 or greater when the first element is multi-lined?

Tags: markdown

I know how to start a numbered list at a number greater than 9. I know how to create a multi-lined list element. But I haven't found a way to do both at the same time. [I've also tested this on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/DanKaplanSES/a5c88f1b2fb9a061791a9cec5ced8bfa) and it behaves the same way as StackOverflow<sup>*</sup>:

#### Rendered list

1. item
2. item

   item
3. item
4. item

   ```
   This is some typescript code:

   function fn(a: string) {
     console.log(a);
   }
   ```
5. item

This line is outside of any list

6. item

   item
7. item
8. item

   item
9. item
10. item

    item

This line is outside of any list.

11. item

item

1. item

   item
2. item

   item

#### Markdown

````
1. item
1. item

   item
1. item
1. item

   ```ts
   This is some typescript code:

   function fn(a: string) {
     console.log(a);
   }
   ```
1. item

This line is outside of any list

6. item

   item
1. item
1. item

   item
1. item
1. item

   item

This line is outside of any list.

11. item

   item
1. item

   item
1. item

   item
````

#### Question

How do I get bullet point `11.` and those that follow to render correctly?

---

<sup>*</sup>: With one exception. [StackOverflow lacks syntax highlighting on the code block, which I believe is a bug.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396055/in-a-markdown-list-indented-fenced-code-blocks-ignore-lack-syntax-highlighting) But that has nothing to do with this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Indentation is significant** and this is described in the rules that define [list items](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list-items) in the CommonMark spec (v0.30):

> **Basic case.** If a sequence of lines *Ls* constitute a sequence of blocks *Bs* starting with a character other than a space or tab, and *M* is a list marker of width *W* followed by 1 ≤ *N* ≤ 4 spaces of indentation, then the result of prepending *M* and the following spaces to the first line of Ls*, and indenting subsequent lines of *Ls* by *W + N* spaces, is a list item with *Bs* as its contents. The type of the list item (bullet or ordered) is determined by the type of its list marker. If the list item is ordered, then it is also assigned a start number, based on the ordered list marker.

In your example, the `item` following ordered list item 11 is not indented enough to be considered as child content of the list item, so it is parsed as a new paragraph:

---

Code:

```
This line is outside of any list.

11. item

   item is now child content
1. item

   item
1. item

   item
```

Rendered:

This line is outside of any list.

11. item

item <-

1. item

   item
2. item

   item

---

By adding an additional space, the item will be indented enough to be parsed as child content of the list item and the following list items will continue as part of the same list (that is no longer broken by a paragraph):

---

Code:

```
This line is outside of any list.

11. item

    item is now child content
1. item

   item
1. item

   item
```

Rendered:

This line is outside of any list.

11. item

    item is now child content
12. item

    item
13. item

    item

Comment: Thank you! Before posting my question I tried to find some official markdown documentation, but I never saw this as a result. This resource will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out what I was doing wrong: I was using 3 spaces for indentation instead of 4. For some reason, 3 works fine until you run into this very specific situation. Here's the same list with 4 spaces instead of 3:

#### Rendered list

1. item
2. item

   item
3. item
4. item

   ```
   This is some typescript code:

   function fn(a: string) {
     console.log(a);
   }
   ```
5. item

This line is outside of any list

6. item

   item
7. item
8. item

   item
9. item
10. item

    item

This line is outside of any list.

11. item

    item
12. item

    item
13. item

    item